# boost interprocess does not clean up after itself

Tags: boost, ipc

I am using boost::interprocess to attempt to share a block of memory between >2 processes. I am allocating the memory using:

```
std::unique_ptr<boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory> tableStorage_;
```

When running the code inside docker/podman, I have to run with `--ipc=host` to be able to execute the code, else it will just happily sit there waiting forever. Not sure for what though.

I am seeing the same behavior in and outside docker/podman. Sometimes when the code exits it doesn't seem to not cleanup `/dev/shm` if it is the last process with a hold on that memory. Is there a way to make sure that `/dev/shm` gets cleaned out when the process exits and it is the last process to hold onto the file in `/dev/shm`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's something your program can/should take care of.

Boost Interprocess (famously) doesn't have a portable robust lock implementation. Meaning that *unless* you do a graceful shutdown, locks might be held, leading to potential deadlock.

I'd suggest using a timed open, guarded with an unconditional `T::remove`. Since that is a destructive operation, perhaps you want to only provide when a certain flag is set (e.g. `--force`)

To detect whether your process is last, you could use shared pointers.

See also e.g. [Boost interprocess shared memory delete object without destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802330/boost-interprocess-shared-memory-delete-object-without-destroy/43869293#43869293)

Comment: Interesting, so I am using python's subprocess to call the c++ code that uses the boost::interprocess. Seems like that is not doing the right thing in terms of shutting down the process.

Comment: That's hard to imagine. It's both easy to do the right thing and important in terms of resource leaks. So I imagine the C++ side is not correctly shutting down **or** you're actively asking for the python side to do the wrong thing (like, killing the child process)